# MySQL merge 2 tables with same Id values

Tags: mysql, merge

I have a MySQL db that has 2 tables that have related information that I need to merge to 1 table.

`Gallery` has an *itemid* that relates to `rbitems` *Id*. Both tables `gallery` and `rbitems` have different column names but both have unique data. I want to merge the two tables based on the *Id* and *itemid* columns.

So how do I merge 2 different tables into 1 based on 1 column having unique values. I'd like to just append the other tables to the merge.

Comment: More info please on what columns are foreign keys to what tables, and the schema (ie columns) of source and destination tables

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence "append the other tables to the merge".  Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` to solve your problem.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   galley a INNER JOIN rbitems b
          on a.itemid = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS (SELECT g.itemid, g.a, g.b, g.c, r.x, r.y, r.z 
    FROM gallery g INNER JOIN rbitems r
    ON g.itemid = r.id
);
```

You may wish to add "AS name" to the members of the select clause.
If you have elements of the original tables that are not represented in the other table you should look into RIGHT, LEFT, or OUTER JOIN instead of INNER.
This assumes that the itemid and id columns are unique--a given itemid/id does not exist multiple times in the same table.